# Unable to retrieve Distinct record from database?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a Database table like below,

```
ID Author  Book

1  Kate    Smuggler

2  Harper  Smuggler

3  Slater  Smuggler

4  Kate   Katy

5  Smitha  Katy
```

i want to retrieve all Book names(Distinct) based on the **author name** and display them on list view, i wrote the code below to Retrieve distinct values

```
int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User"]);

var Li = (from s in Data.TableName where s.Author == UserID select s.Book).Distinct().OrderBy(ID=>ID);

                    ListViewChatList.DataSourceID = "";
                    ListViewChatList.DataSource = Li;
                    ListViewChatList.DataBind();
```

but i get the following error 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

How to solve this ?

Comment: I recommend you to use sql profiler, to check what's going on background.

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı It doesn't compile, so that's not going to be an option.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
select s.Book
```

is selecting just the book (title) part of the record. You can't get back from that to the ID... there can easily be multiple IDs for the same title, as per your sample data.

It's not clear what you'd want that query to return anyway, given that you're getting distinct book *titles* - ignoring the author, would you want IDs 1 and 4? 2 and 5? 3 and 5? Both represent the same set of distinct titles (Smuggler and Katy).

You could potentially *group* by name, and then do whatever you want with the IDs for the books with the shared name - but you really need to consider what your distinctness criterion means for the results.

Here's a query which will give you the lowest ID for each name:

```
var query = from s in Data.TableName
            where s.Author == UserID
            group s.ID by s.Book into g
            select g.OrderBy(id => id).First();
```

It's not clear whether that's what you really need though.

Comment: @user3146981: How to do *what* exactly? Have you considered exactly what you want the query to do. Please see my edit for an example which gives you one ID per distinct name, but that may well not be what you want.

Comment: i just edited database in the wuestion, For example i need Distinct Book for which the author is Kate and they should be sorted by ID

Comment: @user3146981: It's unhelpful to edit the question like that after there are existing answers - it can make those answers less valid. But what would you want to happen if there were multiple books for which the author was Kate and which had a name of Smuggler?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Li = from s in Data.TableName 
    where s.Author == User 
    orderby s.ID 
    select s.Book;
```

Comment: You've removed the `Distinct` here.

Comment: Yup, saw that when I posted then I saw the question was already answered

Answer (score 0):

You're only selecting the `Book` column (a string), and then trying to order by `ID`, which you no longer have access to, and which certainly is not a property of the Book string.

Assume this is your data:

```
ID Author  Book
1  Kate    Smuggler
2  Kate    Smuggler2
3  Kate    Smuggler
4  Frey    Katy
5  Smitha  Katy
```

If you do the following, you'll get the first three books listed above:

```
(from s in Data.TableName where s.Author == "Kate" select s.Book);
```

Then you do a distinct, which reduces the books to the two unique ones (Smuggler and Smuggler2):

```
(...).Distinct();
```

Then you try to order by the ID, but you didn't originally select it so you don't have access to it. And you've taken a `Distinct` on the results, so you've lost some of the detail.

Since the two "Smuggler" books have been reduced to one, but their IDs were 1 and 3 *(in my example)*, what should ordering them do? Should the single "Smuggler" book appear *before* "Smuggler2" or *after*?